# Prologにて「正規表現」を使う方法、もしくはそれに代わる方法はありませんでしょうか

Tags: 正規表現, prolog

こちらの文字列を置換する問題を解いてみています。
http://nojiriko.asia/prolog/seikihyogen9_101.html

要約すると、 `(hoge)あいうえお` を `あいうえお` のように、 **先頭の部分のかっこを削除する** Prologプログラムを書く問題です。

今回は、リンク先にあるようなリスト操作で処理するのではなく、
別解として正規表現もしくは、それに代わる方法を知りたいと考えています。

---

利用している処理系は、以下のいずれかです。

- SWI-Prolog version 5.10.4 for amd64
- SWI-Prolog version 6.6.6 for amd64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWI-Prolog には regex パッケージが用意されていますので、それを使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

["regex" pack for SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=regex)

Comment: version 6.3以降では regexパッケージの regex/4 の Captures:list を使えばいけそうですね。 http://packs.ndrix.com/regex/regex.html#regex/4 

v5系だとパッケージは使えないようでした。 ( パッケージ(通称packs)は V6.1.4 以降に実装されているようです。 https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commit/50a069d7d2e3c1ed84e00785af84d5ca05e17584 )

Answer (score 1):

再帰述語版の定義です。

```
'文字列の先頭のカッコのみ外す。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'(_文字列,_先頭のカッコが外された文字列) :-  
atom_chars(_文字列,_文字リスト),  
'リストの先頭のカッコのみ外す。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'(_文字リスト,_先頭のカッコが外された文字リスト),  
atom_chars(_先頭のカッコが外された文字列,_先頭のカッコが外された文字リスト).  


'リストの先頭のカッコのみ外す。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'(['('|R],_カッコが外されたリスト) :-  
'最初の右カッコ以外はコピー。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'(R,_カッコが外されたリスト),!.  
'リストの先頭のカッコのみ外す。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'(_文字リスト,_文字リスト).  


'最初の右カッコ以外はコピー。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'(['('|_], _) :- !,fail.  
'最初の右カッコ以外はコピー。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'([')'|L],L) :- !.  
'最初の右カッコ以外はコピー。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'([_文字|R1],[_文字|R2]) :-  
'最初の右カッコ以外はコピー。ただしカッコの入れ子は許さない。'(R1,R2).
```